# Derivative of sin(y) = x

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

The lecturer made the comment "the domain of x is between -1 and 1". if the domain of x is 1, the equation turns into

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-1^2}}$$ and x becomes 0

$$\frac{1}{0}$$

Why is 1 a domain of x since it will cause the equation to divide by zero which is indeterminate

Comment: "Between" means "between".

Comment: Between means $-1$ and $1$ are exclusive.

Comment: The domain is $x \in (-1,1)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The step is made for the proof that

$$(\arcsin x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

which is indeed not defined for $x=\pm 1$, that is $x\in(-1,1)$, since the tangent at that point is vertical.

[image]

Comment: And it's not even an interior point of the domain.

Comment: @Botond sorry what domain are you referring to?

Comment: The domain of the $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(x)$. The $-1$ and $1$ are not in the $\text{int}(\text{dom}(f))$, so we can't take the derivative there.

Comment: @Botond Yes it is true, but this case we can not even define the one side derivative at the limit points of the domain, as for the function $\sqrt x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to emphasise that it does not exist, because it does not even meet the requirements of the definition. But we can take the limit of the one-sided derivative, and it will be $\infty$ - or visually a vertical tanget line - as you mentioned it.

Comment: Gimusi.Formidable!

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks! not so difficult :)

Comment: Gimusi.The gift is to make something out of it. Formidable! Comme presque toujours:)

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks for your kind appreciation!